# Where can i find yahoo yql stocks result xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, yahoo, yql

I want to develop an application which uses results from the yahoo finance data. I can get the results from the yql query. But i wanted to convert the XML to C# classes. I know how to convert XSD to C# classes, de-serialize and serialize them. But how do i get the XSD or the XML schema as defined by yahoo.

Thank you.

Comment: @Kiva nope. I was trying to write a hobby project around it .. you dont need this you an convert it to JSon and do what ever you want to do

Answer (score 0):

It is open sourced here, you can take a look:

https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/tree/master/yahoo/finance